# Problemas al Publicar WEB API MVC en IIS 7 (No se conecta a la Base de Datos)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, asp.net-web-api

Estoy tratando de publicar una web api asp.net mvc en iis(local) la api me devuelve unos datos json estoy usando entity framework pero cuando accedo a la url que me devuelve los datos me muestra un error como que no se puede conectar a la base de datos
[image: Error bd]

Me imagino que esta relacionado con la cadena de conexión no se si le tengo que cambiar algo ya que si lo correo desde vs si me corre bien la api y la estoy publicando en la misma pc 
esta es la cadena de conexion que usa

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersonaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LATIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Persona;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Es la misma que me genera el vs y repito si ejecuto la api desde el vs si me devuelve los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probe cambiando la identidad en el iis a local system pero siempre me muestra el mismo error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta cuando entro a la url que me devuelve los datos porque la pagina de inicio si me la muestra(osea que si esta publicada en el iis).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal seria que uses la cadena de conexión con un usuario de sql server(crea un usuario o usa el usuario sa)

```
data source = ServidorSQL; initial catalog = BaseDatos; user id = Usuario; password = Contraseña
```

Prueba haciendo ese cambio en la cadena de conexion